# SQL query with special character(Accent character, é) is not giving expected result

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, utf-8

This is my actual query:
*select id,name_en,name_fr from stores where name_en like "%l'é%" or description_en like "%l'é%" order by name_en*

It is giving proper result in sqlite browser. (FYI: Slight changed query to post here)

But our sqlite3 API function `sqlite3_prepare_v2` only accepts **SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded**. So, I should have to convert above query string to UTF-8 character pointer.

I tried to achieve it by following code,

```
const char * queryPointer = [finalQuery UTF8String];
int resultCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, queryPointer, -1, &compileStatement, NULL);
```

but It is giving empty result set. After looked into `queryPointer` I found that **é** in my query string is replaced by some unwanted characters. So, I think problem lies here. I believe this is something related to encoding.

I have tried several combination of encoding, below is one of them

```
NSData *dataOfParam1 = [sqlStatement dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *unicodeStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataOfParam1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *unichar2 = [unicodeStr1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Might be I am in wrong direction so, other work arounds are also accepted.

**Edit:**

Actually, `finalQuery` is static search query except **l'é**, it is a search term.

**Second Edit:**

One interesting thing I found is if we are searching **L’E`** (Please note case difference)then search is working and I am getting result. but I am astonished why this is case sensitive? Same thing is working in *SqliteManager* plugin of firefox without problem of case sensitivity.

Comment: `UTF8String` is correct; apparently `finalQuery` is not encoded correctly.

Comment: @CL. Please see my edits. It would be great if you can provide more idea on encoding or what you are saying

Comment: Show the code that creates `finalQuery`.